# How to configure a sshd_config that allow SFTP but not SSH (to start a bash)?

Tags: ssh

A Ubuntu 16 server is used as an SFTP-server.
This server is located in an DMZ VLAN.

This server must be configured so that:

- From the external internet only SFTP can be used to login but ssh cannot
  be used (to start a bash).
- From the internal network, it must be possible to log in with both SFTP and SSH (to start a bash).

Two `sshd` can be started for this, each with its own `sshd_config` file and own port number.

How can a `sshd_config` be configured in such a way that it is possible to 
login with SFTP but not with ssh (to start a bash)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I allow or disallow access to SSH on a SFTP server?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/402302/how-can-i-allow-or-disallow-access-to-ssh-on-a-sftp-server)

Answer (score 1):

*Note: I am unable to fully test this at the moment - posted in the hope that it will be useful*

This should be possible with a single sshd instance, by using a `Match` block at the bottom of the server's `sshd_config` file.

```
Match Address *,!192.168.1.0/24
        ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

Replace `192.168.1.0/24` with your own LAN CIDR address range.

See also [How can the Address condition in a Match conditional block in sshd_config be negated?](https://serverfault.com/questions/408284/how-can-the-address-condition-in-a-match-conditional-block-in-sshd-config-be-neg)