# Jailkit: does it work in 22.04?

Tags: chroot

I'm following [these instructions](https://olivier.sessink.nl/jailkit/howtos_sftp_scp_only.html) for setting up sftp and scp (although I'd like to add rsync too) but when the jailed account logs in, it immediately disconnects without any errors I can see.

The doc says that if this happens you need to `journalctl|grep jk_`, which gives this (nor errors):

```
jk_chrootsh[3157425]: now entering jail /home/jail for user jailtest (1001) with arguments -c /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
```

Most if not all of the information I can find on Jailkit seems pretty old, although I see jailkit itself was updated in Oct 2021. Does anyone know if it still works on Ubuntu or how I can track down what error is happening?

**I have used Jailkit successfully in the past with Ubuntu 18. I'm starting to think that something fundamental has changed in 20 (snaps, perhaps?) which has disabled Jailkit in some way.**

/home/jail/etc/passwd:

```
jailtest:x:1001:1004:tester,,,:/home/jailtest:/usr/sbin/jk_lsh
```

/etc/jailkit/jk_lsh.ini:

```
[jailtest]
paths= /usr/bin, /usr/lib/openssh
executables= /usr/bin/scp, /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
```

ldd /usr/sbin/jk_lsh

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffce6d11000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f91ffee6000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f920011f000)
```

`strace chroot /home/jail/ /usr/sbin/jk_lsh` and other things doesn't seem to show anything missing.

`scp -v ./test.txt jailtest@xxx.uk:/home/jailtest/` from the client shows no errors and just hangs up:

```
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: channel 0: setting env LANG = "en_GB.UTF-8"
debug1: Sending subsystem: sftp
debug1: pledge: fork
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Transferred: sent 4172, received 4132 bytes, in 0.4 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 9390.9, received 9300.9
debug1: Exit status 3
scp: Connection closed
```

My sshd_config is:

```
PermitRootLogin no 
PubkeyAuthentication yes
PasswordAuthentication no 
PermitEmptyPasswords no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
UsePAM yes
X11Forwarding yes
PrintMotd no
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
Subsystem       sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
AllowGroups ssh-users # I've put the jailed user into this, removing it causes a permissions error
```

Comment: It might be simpler using `internal-sftp` as the jail and disabling normal SSH shell

Comment: @DanielT It says in the docs that if you do that it will not start a shell, and thus bypass jk_chrootsh, so it would (I assume) be unsafe to do that?

Comment: I meant uninstall JailKit and figure out how to use internal-sftp to do this natively.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/q/402302/1004020 or https://askubuntu.com/q/134425/1004020

Comment: Ah, OK. Yes I think you may be right.

Comment: Just realised: no, `internal-sftp` won't work as I need to have users using public key auth (eg scp). So, back to JailKit.

Comment: What? Public key auth should be at the sshd level, and is at the authentication stage, before any command is run. It has nothing to do with whether it's internal-sftp or jailkit. As you said, jailkit looks unmaintained

Comment: I was unable to comment on your other question before you deleted it, but iirc the *tricky* part is where exactly to place the authorized_keys file versus the home directory in the passwd file - see for example [Public key authorization on sftp chroot directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23448900/public-key-authorization-on-sftp-chroot-directory).

Comment: (cont.)  or you could move it outside the user's home altogether, somewhere like `/etc/ssh/authorized_keys/%u` as here [How to properly chroot when using key based authentication within openssh-server](https://serverfault.com/questions/910951/how-to-properly-chroot-when-using-key-based-authentication-within-openssh-server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer to this is "yes". Before I started investigting @DanielT's very good suggestions in the comments, I decided to remove and re-install the JailKit package. I then re-created my jail with:

`jk_init -v -j /home/jail netutils jk_lsh`

(Note that this appears different to the official documentation.)

The `netutils` alias in that command allows access to sftp, scp and rsync which is what I was interested in - see `/etc/jailkit/jk_init.ini`.

For some reason, I got a Python error when I ran the jk_init command (jailkit v2.23-1), but running it again appeared to clear the problem.

Jailed accounts were then able to log in and were chrooted correctly.